# weak transaction in secp256k1

Tags: cryptography, math

My question is related to weak signature vulnerability testing where a hypothetical attacker does not know the values of the nonce or private key itself, but can determine that the nonce 'k1' is designed  by private key 'd' to message hash z , such that: k = 128 MSB bit of z + 128 bit MSB of d (privatekey)
example:

d= private key in hex
z= message hash
k= nonce; where nonce is equal first 128 bit of z + 128 bit of d

d= 0x**036ed4f5f383049827edc4fe337f46f8**3a240b124242620b02b97552b2fc11a4
z= **f55ab477c48f9afaf1a72ab448bf96b4**a05f336f7a1e27e08993308dfaa783b5
k = f55ab477c48f9afaf1a72ab448bf96b4 + 036ed4f5f383049827edc4fe337f46f8
k= 0xf55ab477c48f9afaf1a72ab448bf96b4036ed4f5f383049827edc4fe337f46f8

signature:
r= 62326678398279634483781267842729177896577268934832461436294590773005653623297
s= 78373122694400608572761948114834235891083358005495335895684705221713649603747
z= 110976909682006680432155795488402189554785886863009729379902726621537291961269

I have searched the stack exchanges and various articles and research papers and have not found a workable solution to this problem. My own linear algebra is not as strong as I would like it (it's been a number of years), and my attempts have not been successful.

Is there any way to calculate k or privatekey?

N: Finite field of the secp256k1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this would be trivial to break.

Let's say that:

- *z = z<sub>0</sub> + 2<sup>128</sup>z<sub>1</sub>*, with 128-bit *z<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>1</sub>*.
- *d = d<sub>0</sub> + 2<sup>128</sup>d<sub>1</sub>*, with 128-bit *d<sub>0</sub>, d<sub>1</sub>*.

In that case, according to your construction, *k = d<sub>1</sub> + 2<sup>128</sup>z<sub>1</sub>*.

For ECDSA signatures *(r,s)*:

- We know *s = k<sup>-1</sup>(z + rd) (mod n)* (the signing equation)
- Put otherwise: *sk = z + rd (mod n)*
- Substituting the above: *s(d<sub>1</sub> + 2<sup>128</sup>z<sub>1</sub>) = z<sub>0</sub> + 2<sup>128</sup>z<sub>1</sub> + r(d<sub>0</sub> + 2<sup>128</sup>d<sub>1</sub>) (mod n)*.
- Grouping: *rd<sub>0</sub> + (2<sup>128</sup>r - s)d<sub>1</sub> = 2<sup>128</sup>z<sub>1</sub>(s - 1) - z<sub>0</sub> (mod n)*.

All variables in the last equation above except for *d<sub>0</sub>* and *d<sub>1</sub>* are known. Finding solutions for those restricted to range *[0,2<sup>128</sup>)* is a simple lattice reduction, which likely has at most a few solutions. Those can be tested exhaustively.